# Visual Studio Windows Phone emulator under Azure VM

Tags: visual-studio, azure, windows-phone, virtual-machine

I am trying to run the Visual Studio Windows Phone Emulator but I get those errors :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '8BDF218D-FDBB-4A97-90F9-3AA33B559A92'.': 
NullReferenceException - Invalid pointer    App1



Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found.    App1
```

And the Emulator fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an emulator on a Azure VM. Hyper-V cannot be nested, which is what you would need.

Right now the best approach is to run the emulator locally (Win8/10) or download the files and install on a Windows Phone.

Are you running Windows or a Mac/Linux?

Comment: I am running Windows, are you sure about the emulator, because there are examples for android emulator under VM.

Comment: The Windows Emulator uses and needs Hyper-V to run and in Azure there cannot be nested hyper-v machines. Android is different. It uses intellij